# Can't connect a TextMeshProUGUI to my prefab ind Unity/C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Basicly, I'm building a 2D-platformer und added a working coin-collection-programm. But after implementing the charakter-respawn, the respawned charakter can't pick up any items. I figured out, that the needed connection between the text mesh (for displaying the count) and the prefab of the player. The coinpicker-script of the prefab can't connect to the textbox and I can't drag the mesh in manually...

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using Cinemachine;

 public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public static LevelManager instance;
 public Transform respawnPoint;
 public GameObject playerPrefab;

 public CinemachineVirtualCameraBase cam;

 private void Awake(){
     instance = this;
 }
 public void Respawn (){
     GameObject player = Instantiate(playerPrefab, respawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
     cam.Follow = player.transform;
 }

}
```

[A picture of the problem in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rnsnC.png)

The shown script below is attached to the player and the player prefab and needs a connection to the TMPro text, but I can't connect it prefab side

```
 using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using TMPro;

    public class CoinPicker : MonoBehaviour
    {
    private float coin = 0;
    public TextMeshProUGUI textCoins;

    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other){
        if (other.transform.tag == "Coin"){
            coin++;
            
            textCoins.text = coin.ToString();
            Destroy(other.gameObject);

            
        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Can you clarify your issue a bit more? I fail to see how the above code relates to the picture you had added. Are you saying that the script `Coin Picker` can't have the `TMPro.Text` dragged into the public field? Does the player have the text component childed to it, so you want to set the reference after it is spawned? Then create a reference to the text of the Player prefab and have a getter method to assign it to the `Coin Picker` script. If you can post more clarification I can give you an actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void Start() 
{
    // THE NAME OF THE OBJECT ON THE SCENE
    textCoin = GameObject.Find("CoinText");
}
```

For this, it is enough to enter a code to find the TextMeshPro object in the Start of the object.
Each time the object respawns, it searches and identifies this object within the scene.
GameObject.Find